# How can i write unit test for Suspend function and stateflow in android

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to write unit test for my application. I am using Mockk to mock classes.

This is my unit test

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
class MainViewModalTest {

    private lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModal
    private val savedStateHandle = mockk<SavedStateHandle>(relaxed = true)
    private val randomFactUseCase = mockk<RandomFactUseCase>()

    @get:Rule
    val mainDispatcher = MainDispatcherRule()


    @Before
    fun setup() {
        viewModel = MainViewModal(randomFactUseCase, savedStateHandle)
    }

    @Test
    fun `When fetchRandomFact succeeds, update UI state with fact`() = runBlockingTest {
        // Given
        coEvery { randomFactUseCase.invoke() } returns Result.Success(RandomFact(data = listOf("Some interesting fact")), 200)

        // When
        viewModel.fetchRandomFact()

        // Then
        val expectedUiState = UiState(loading = false, fact = "Some interesting fact", error = "")
        assert(viewModel.uiState.value == expectedUiState)
    }
}
class MainDispatcherRule(private val testDispatcher: TestDispatcher = UnconfinedTestDispatcher()) :
    TestWatcher() {

    override fun starting(description: Description) {
        super.starting(description)
        Dispatchers.setMain(testDispatcher)
    }

    override fun finished(description: Description) {
        super.finished(description)
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
    }
}
```

it is failing with this error

> Exception in thread "Test worker @coroutine#1"
> io.mockk.MockKException: no answer found for
> RandomFactUseCase(#2).invoke(continuation {}) among the configured
> answers: ()

This is my viewModel:

```
@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModal @Inject constructor(
    private val randomFactUseCase: RandomFactUseCase,
    private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,

    ) : ViewModel() {
    init {
        fetchRandomFact()
    }

    val uiState: StateFlow<UiState> = savedStateHandle.getStateFlow("fact", UiState(loading = true))

    fun fetchRandomFact() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            setState(loading = true)
            when (val response = randomFactUseCase()) {
                is Result.Success -> {
                    val fact =
                        if (response.data?.data?.isNotEmpty() == true) response.data.data[0] else ""
                    setState(
                        loading = false,
                        fact = fact,
                        error = if (fact.isBlank()) "No fact available!" else ""
                    )
                }

                is Result.Error -> {
                    setState(
                        loading = false,
                        fact = "",
                        error = response.exception.message
                            ?: "Something went wrong! Please try again"
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun setState(loading: Boolean = true, fact: String = "", error: String = "") {
        savedStateHandle["fact"] = UiState(loading = loading, fact = fact, error = error)
    }
}

@Parcelize
data class UiState(val loading: Boolean = true, val fact: String = "", val error: String = "") :
    Parcelable
```

Not sure what I am missing here. Although I feel that I am pretty close.

EDIT1:
As per @broots suggestion I have updated the viewModel like this:

```
@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModal @Inject constructor(
    private val randomFactUseCase: RandomFactUseCase,
    private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,

    ) : ViewModel() {
    init {
        invokeFunction()
    }

    fun invokeFunction() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            fetchRandomFact()
        }
    }

    val uiState: StateFlow<UiState> = savedStateHandle.getStateFlow("fact", UiState(loading = true))

    suspend fun fetchRandomFact() {
        setState(loading = true)
        when (val response = randomFactUseCase()) {
            is Result.Success -> {
                val fact =
                    if (response.data?.data?.isNotEmpty() == true) response.data.data[0] else ""
                setState(
                    loading = false,
                    fact = fact,
                    error = if (fact.isBlank()) "No fact available!" else ""
                )
            }

            is Result.Error -> {
                setState(
                    loading = false,
                    fact = "",
                    error = response.exception.message ?: "Something went wrong! Please try again"
                )
            }
        }
    }

    private fun setState(loading: Boolean = true, fact: String = "", error: String = "") {
        savedStateHandle["fact"] = UiState(loading = loading, fact = fact, error = error)
    }
}
```

It did not solve the issue. (Adding this for reference)

Comment: Your `fetchRandomFact()` schedules running a background task. There is no good way to test such background operations, because they run in a separate context and it is not trivial to wait for them to finish. Coroutines generally encourage to use suspend functions and wait in-place instead of launching new coroutines in the background. If `fetchRandomFact()` would be a suspend function and not launch anything, your tests would work correctly.

Comment: hello @broot, if my assumption is correct, `coEvery return` is to immediately return a value, right?? if `fetchRandomFact` is suspend how should I invoke it from compose?

Comment: Sorry, I won't help you with Compose specifically, but a common pattern when bridging UI frameworks with coroutines is to launch a coroutine early in the event handler, then stick to this coroutine by using suspend functions. If we use a lot of functions that launch their work in the background, then the code quickly becomes hard to test and maintain. The whole point of coroutines is to write sequential code.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. Let me try this and update here. Thanks @broot

Comment: @broot I did try what you have mentioned but I am still facing the same issue. I have updated the question with your suggestion in the question as an edit. Please take a look if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using test dispatcher that performs actions directly when called, and in your viewmodel you have call to usecase inside constructor.
This way the mock is called still being inside @Before block

If you want to define mock responses in test body, then you could make viewmodel variable lazy

```kotlin
    private val savedStateHandle = mockk<SavedStateHandle>(relaxed = true)
    private val randomFactUseCase = mockk<RandomFactUseCase>()

    private val viewModel: MainViewModal by lazy {
        MainViewModal(randomFactUseCase, savedStateHandle)
    }

    @Test
    fun `When fetchRandomFact succeeds, update UI state with fact`() = runBlockingTest {
        // Given
        coEvery { randomFactUseCase.invoke() } returns Result.Success(RandomFact(data = listOf("Some interesting fact")), 200)

        // When
        viewModel // dereferencing lazy property will call constructor, which calls method under test

        // Then
        val expectedUiState = UiState(loading = false, fact = "Some interesting fact", error = "")
        assert(viewModel.uiState.value == expectedUiState)
    }
```

Comment: hello, thank you for the answer. The fetchRandomFact is public and it can be called outside of the constructor too. I tried your solution. But I am getting Assertion failed at `assert(viewModel.uiState.value == expectedUiState)`

Comment: I suggest to use junit `org.junit.Assert.assertEquals` - it gives better description when condition is not met. In your case is that you are using mockk for savestatehandle and creating stateflow from it gives mock flow with mock data that is not updated on write, as mock does not know how it should behave. This will require to write more inteligent version of mock or run this test as instrumental (running on device) and give actual implementation of savestatehandle

Comment: update on comment above: it looks like savestatehandle is safe to use in unit tests as it is. I thought it have bundle references in it as I remember I had to mock it in past but it looks like things had changed

Comment: any idea why its happening? in my case? I can share a github repo if you have time to look into it

Comment: you can just use actul implementation in tests `private val savedStateHandle = SavedStateHandle()`, no need to mock it

Comment: Thank you for your help. This was the issue. Will award the bounty when it opens up.